# Generalizing rest calls

Tags: java, android, rest

I am using REST for my web services. 
Here is my sample GET request I am using. I have so many GET, Post methods in my code. I need to generalize these methods ,just to ensure that I am not missing AUTH TOKEN to add with header.

How can I generalize this code? By extending some class how to do it.

My intention is just to put HTTP header once in the code and reuse it everywhere.

What is the standard practice on this? Or do my current method looks fine? Expecting expert advices. Thanks in advance.

My current code:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();


    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SystemConstants.CUSTOMER_SUMMARY_URL
            + "mobile=" + mCreditMobileNumber + "&businessid="
            + mBusinessId);

    httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", mAuthToken);

    GetClientSummaryResponse summaryResponse = null;

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            summaryResponse = gson.fromJson(reader,
                    GetClientSummaryResponse.class);



        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a sort of utility class that handles creating a HttpGet object and just returns that. Sort of like what I wrote below.

```
public class MyHttpUtility
{
    public HttpGet createHttpGet( String mAuthToken, String mCreditMobileNumber, mBusinessId )
    {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SystemConstants.CUSTOMER_SUMMARY_URL
            + "mobile=" + mCreditMobileNumber + "&businessid="
            + mBusinessId);
        httpGet.addHeader( "Authenticate", mAuthToken );
        return httpGet;
    }       
}
```

That way whenever I need a request I know it's always constructed in one central place instead of duplicating the code in a bunch of different places.

```
MyHttpUtility httpUtil = new MyHttpUtility();
HttpGet httpGet = httpUtil.createHttpGet( "token", "ccmobile", "businessid" );
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
// ... and the rest of the response logic
```

Comment: Okay used this logic. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I should start by saying I am fairly new to android as well and made up something recently for a project I started but didn't get around to finishing yet. The API portion is fairly complete and can be adapted to most other APIs. I specifically built it around providing methods of callback to the interface post response from the API. Here's a link to the code http://ftp-ns-drop.com/stack/api.zip, Included is one of my activities called LoginActivity. I included it so you could see how the api calls are invoked and how they are received.

Heres my class structure.

APIClient - this class contains all my methods for creating api calls like login(username, password, callback), the credentials for our current session and our HTTPClient.

APITask - The actual AsyncTask(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that handles the execution of our http request and then passes back the result to our APIClient. the async task is of course important to allow the GUI thread to continue to execute while the request is being processed.

APICallback - An interface that can be added using annotations to any class, the class is then passed to the APIClient when requests are made and a method then serves as a callback for the API. (note: I made this an annotation interface not because it has to be but because I wanted an excuse to use annotations :), It may make more sense to just make it an interface)

JSONResponse - The response for any API call, contains the HTTP request, the HTTP response and the data response, this is passed back to the callback method defined by APICallback.